# Products not displaying in Prestashop (default theme)

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have everything working in my local system, but when I moved the site to live server [http://laptoplab.rf.gd](http://laptoplab.rf.gd/)

The products are listing in home page, but not in inner pages, which is accessible through menu.

Please help.

Prestashop Version: 1.7.2.2
Theme: Default theme

Comment: are you currently using a "clean url" module on your live site to remove the id's from the slug(s)?

Comment: @Aurora No I am not using "clean url" module, "friendly url" is already enabled. I am a begginer please forgive in any mistakes

Comment: Did you try to clear the cache? If you go to advanced parameters -> performance on the top right of your page you can clear it.

Comment: Also: go to prefrences -> products. You will see "pagination" and the input field "products per page". Is the value higher then 0? if not, set it to the number of products you want to have displayed per page, e.g. 12